# error: "component factory found for" when using dialog.open form angluer service even though it's included in entryComponents

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-material

### Proplem description

when calling ***dialog.open*** from  ***Injectable Service*** it fails with Error

### Error

---

```
    core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for LessonEndedDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    Error: No component factory found for LessonEndedDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

---

### 1. Dialog Component

---

```
  @Component()
  export class LessonEndedDialogComponent {}
```

---

### 2. Sub Module

---

```
  @NgModule({
    declarations: [LessonEndedDialogComponent],
    entryComponents: [LessonEndedDialogComponent],
  })
  export class CoursesModule { }
```

---

### 3. Root Module

---

```
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [AppComponent,],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

---

### 4. Root Routes

---

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'courses',
        loadChildren: () => import('./courses/courses.module').then(mod => mod.CoursesModule)
      },
     ];

    @NgModule({
       imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
       exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

---

### 5. Injectable Service

---

```
    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class NavigationService {

            constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {  }

            displayDialog() {
                this.dialog.open(LessonEndedDialogComponent);
            }
    }
```

---

### Solution A

change

```
    providedIn: 'root'
```

to

```
    providedIn: CoursesModule
```

### Soution A , fails

- waring

> Circular dependency detected:

- error

> Cannot access 'CoursesModule' before initialization

### Solution B

becase

```
    providedIn: 'root'
```

move

```
    entryComponents: [
            LessonEndedDialogComponent
    ],
```

to Root

```
    AppModule
```

### Soution B , works

but LessonEndedDialogComponent is form ***sub Module***

this will be make the ***root Module*** dependen on the ***sub Module***

witch is bad for separation of Modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### import Injectable Service manually

#### step 1

change

```
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
```

to

```
  @Injectable()
```

#### Step 2

use ***providers*** array on the ***Sub Module***

```
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [LessonEndedDialogComponent],
        entryComponents: [LessonEndedDialogComponent],
        providers: [NavigationService],
    })
    export class CoursesModule { }
```